# Is it possible to get the specified docker ram limits inside of an container?

Tags: docker, containers

I create a container with 1024 mib ram limit in docker, is it possible to get the limit as Variable inside the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can findout the limit with the command below.

```
 # [root@node01 1.13.2]# docker run -it -m 536870912 alpine sh

/ # cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes

536870912
```